# How can I prevent my image from opening when long click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code like this:

```
<button onmousedown="alert('Hi!');">Some text</button>
```

But when I try to long click it (that’s why I put `onMouseDown`event), my text is selected instead of only execute my script. How can I prevent my text from being selected when trying to execute `onMouseDown` event?

Comment: Have you tried `preventDefault`?

Comment: There's nothing in the code shown that would cause an image to open when long-clicking (or short-clicking, or any other interaction) the button. The only thing the button might do is submit a form it was a descendant of. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @Heretirc Monkey my title is bug

Comment: Yeah, all you said is right, but why Stack Overflow in English is bad with the new programmers :( I will go back to es.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `user-select: none` property for that . So text is not selected by user